# Nginx startup prompt [emerg] no "events" section in configuration

Tags: nginx, openresty, web-application-firewall

In the X-WAF deployment, you need to create a new nginx configuration file. However, when testing the nginx configuration, an error is found and nginx cannot be started.

I refer to http://blog.51cto.com/14071176/2318054，I did it step by step according to the configuration in the article, but I had a problem.

```
root@VM-0-6-ubuntu:~# /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

root@VM-0-6-ubuntu:~# /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx
nginx: [emerg] no "events" section in configuration
```

Under normal circumstances, executing /usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -t will have two successes, but mine is a success and a failure.

Comment: Just add `events { }` above the `http {` line.

Comment: Thanks, I used the nginx.conf configuration file in another website to fix this problem. It is indeed a problem in nginx.conf.The other site I refer to is http://kongdewei.cn/2017/08/11/%E7%9C%8B%E6%88%91%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E6%90%AD%E5%BB%BA%E4%B8%80%E6%AC%BE%E6%96%B9%E4%BE%BF%E6%98%93%E7%94%A8%E7%9A%84%E4%BA%91WAF/

Answer (score 235):

Just add `events { }` above the `http {` line:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        # Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what this does?

Comment: @BenBieler it is the section for connection processing directives. For example, worker_connections 768;

http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#events

Comment: It doesn't do anything, actually, unless you put something inside of it. Weird that an empty `events {}` solves the startup check.

Answer (score 28):

Put above http{}

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
```

Nginx worker_connections : sets the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process.

Comment: It must work yes, but what if you just want to keep the default value ? Then defining an empty `events {}` section is better IMO.